# VSCode puts empty lines between styles?

Tags: css, visual-studio-code

I can prevent extra blank lines in the HTML part of my file with this:

```
"html.format.extraLiners": " "
```

but how can I prevent extra blank lines between styles from the style section at the top of the file?

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        #c {
            background-color: red;
        }

        #b {
            background-color: green;
        }

        #c {
            background-color: blue;
        }

    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="a">A</div>
    <div id="b">B</div>
    <div id="c">C</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've looked for what should be a simple solution to this for a long time.  Didn't want to install an extension just to handle something so simple, but that's the only way I've found to fix it...

- Install Beautify.
- Create file .jsbeautifyrc in your directory structure above wherever you want it to work.  I put it in my main
  projects folder so it works on everything.
- Add the rule below to the
  file.

  {
      "newline_between_rules": false
  }

Comment: It's been almost two years since this post/answer. Has a better method emerged or are we still stuck with installing Beautify?

Comment: I am no longer using Beautify and my CSS is not double-spaced when I paste it it.  But... I looked everywhere and can't find a setting for it so maybe MS changed that formatting?  I did find one line in my settings.json that I thought might be responsible: "html.format.extraLiners": "",  But when I remove it, it doesn't seem to make a difference.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Code is still adding the lines for me, unfortunately. Anyone else have a suggestion?